# Duplicate hash key in request when posting a form with a checkbox using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have a checkbox iagree and when I am submitting the form I am getting

```
obj[iagree] : 0
obj[iagree] : 1
```

in the request. I don't know why is this?

Comment: Can you post your form code in your view?

Comment: Did you see my answer? Did it help you to understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected when using form helpers like `check_box_tag`.
This helper create a hidden field just before the check box with the same name and the value `0`.

The reason for this hidden field is to solve the issue, that the browser sends no parameter at all when a check box is unchecked.
So it is not possible to destingish, whether there is no check box in the form or the check box is uncheced.
With this workaround an unchecked check box is returned with value `0` and a checked checkbox with value `1`.
The second parameter just overwrites the hidden field, if checked.

In your `params[]` you will always see `obj[iagree]` with either `0` or `1`.